Can I use a handheld spectrophotometer to calibrate my TCS3200-based fluid color assessment system?
I'm trying to build a system that measures color and turbidity within the tube that exits a patient's brain. Using a TCS3200 sensor and an Arduino micro, and a custom-made housing to ensure a dark measuring chamber, I am able to get measurements. Inspired by the answer provided by @marcus-müller, I've rewritten the code.
#include <SPI.h> 
#include <SD.h>

// Define pins connected to the TCS3200 sensor
#define S0 8
#define S1 9
#define S2 10
#define S3 11
#define sensorOut 12

// Store the calibration value for clear CSF readings (TO-DO CALIBRATION!!!)
int baselineClearPeriodCount = 0; 
int baselineRedPeriodCount = 0; 
int baselineGreenPeriodCount = 0; 
int baselineBluePeriodCount = 0; 

// Specifies the target count to be achieved within the dynamic time adjustment
const int targetCount = 360; 

// Variables to store counts for each color and clear reading
int redPeriodCount = 0;
int greenPeriodCount = 0;
int bluePeriodCount = 0;
int clearPeriodCount = 0;

// Timeout setting for the pulseIn() function
const int pulseTimeout = 2000; // Timeout in microseconds


void setup() {
  // Set up the pins for controlling the TCS3200 sensor
  pinMode(S0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S3, OUTPUT);

  // Set up the pin for receiving the sensor's output 
  pinMode(sensorOut, INPUT);

  // Begin serial communication for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // --- Reading Red Color ---
  digitalWrite(S2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(S3, LOW);
  unsigned long startTime = millis();
  redPeriodCount = 0;

  // Dynamic adjustment of measurement time
  unsigned long currentTime = millis(); 
  int dynamicMeasurementTime = 50; 
  while (currentTime - startTime < dynamicMeasurementTime) { 
      int pulseWidth = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW, pulseTimeout);
      if (pulseWidth > 0) {
          redPeriodCount++; 
          if (redPeriodCount >= targetCount) {
              dynamicMeasurementTime = currentTime - startTime; 
              break; 
          }
      } 
      currentTime = millis();
  }

  // --- Reading Green Color ---
  digitalWrite(S2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S3, HIGH);
  startTime = millis();
  greenPeriodCount = 0; 
  // Dynamic adjustment of measurement time 
  currentTime = millis(); 
  dynamicMeasurementTime = 50; 
  while (currentTime - startTime < dynamicMeasurementTime) { 
      int pulseWidth = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW, pulseTimeout);
      if (pulseWidth > 0) {
          greenPeriodCount++; 
          if (greenPeriodCount >= targetCount) {
              dynamicMeasurementTime = currentTime - startTime; 
              break; 
          }
      } 
      currentTime = millis();
  }

  // --- Reading Blue Color ---
  digitalWrite(S2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(S3, HIGH);
  startTime = millis();
  bluePeriodCount = 0; 
  // Dynamic adjustment of measurement time
  currentTime = millis(); 
  dynamicMeasurementTime = 50; 
  while (currentTime - startTime < dynamicMeasurementTime) { 
      int pulseWidth = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW, pulseTimeout);
      if (pulseWidth > 0) {
          bluePeriodCount++; 
          if (bluePeriodCount >= targetCount) {
              dynamicMeasurementTime = currentTime - startTime; 
              break; 
          }
      } 
      currentTime = millis();
  }

  // --- Reading Clear Channel (for Turbidity) ---
  digitalWrite(S2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S3, LOW);
  startTime = millis();
  clearPeriodCount = 0; 
  // Dynamic adjustment of measurement time
  currentTime = millis(); 
  dynamicMeasurementTime = 50; 
  while (currentTime - startTime < dynamicMeasurementTime) { 
      int pulseWidth = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW, pulseTimeout);
      if (pulseWidth > 0) {
          clearPeriodCount++; 
          if (clearPeriodCount >= targetCount) {
              dynamicMeasurementTime = currentTime - startTime; 
              break; 
          }
      } 
      currentTime = millis();
  }

    // --- Calculate Turbidity (Reduction in Clear Reading) ---
    int turbidityReductionPercent = (baselineClearPeriodCount - clearPeriodCount) * 100 / baselineClearPeriodCount;  
    
    // Color Changes (compared to baselines)    
    int redChangePercent = (redPeriodCount - baselineRedPeriodCount) * 100 / baselineRedPeriodCount;
    int greenChangePercent = (greenPeriodCount - baselineGreenPeriodCount) * 100 / baselineGreenPeriodCount; 
    int blueChangePercent = (bluePeriodCount - baselineBluePeriodCount) * 100 / baselineBluePeriodCount;


  // SD Card stuff
// etc. etc.

However, this leaves me with the circular problem of setting both the target count and the LED intensity. We do have a handheld spectrophotometer, and I've created a white-colored chamber for the tube to pass through (which also serves as a light-reflecting device internally and a dark chamber that prevents ambient light). Using a potentiometer, I'll adjust the LED intensity until the correlation between the TCS3200 and the handheld device is the highest.
But there are a few issues:

The spectrophotometer shines its own light and measures the light reflected upon it, and I have no good way of disabling the device's internal light source. How inaccurate would it be to use an additional LED that shines light through the PVC tube, similar to what I'm doing with the TCS3200 chip?

The TCS3200 outputs RGB values rather than the spectrophotometer's CIE outputs. I'm not sure the Arduino Micro will be able to keep up with onboard calculations. Would it be better to convert it on my PC to run a correlation analysis? If not, I've found this library that I think is the conversion equation I need.



I think the best solution is to have an identical LED+dark chamber setup that measures the same PVC tube contents, convert CIE outputs to RGB ones on my computer and run a correlation coefficient analysis on the collected data.

I did custom spectro instrumentation for industry using Vis wavelengths and near IR. The spectros I used were from a variety of sources, but including Ocean Optics. All of them required calibration steps that required a standard, well-designed and machined calibration stand and two types of optical sources -- a merc-argon lamp (cheap) for wavelength calibration of the pixels and an NIST-calibrated tungsten lamp (not cheap) for intensity calibration. And software I wrote generating calibration data that was later used to make measurements. I'm not sure you appreciate this side of the process.

They let you build stuff to go in a patient's brain? And what is the accuracy of this handheld device?"

@SolarMike, I should say, exits the brain. No, it doesn't go into the brain; it attaches to an FDA-approved device externally...

@periblepsis I see this as pilot research. I'm trying to keep it simple yet reliable enough. It doesn't have to be space-grade accurate; it just needs to be accurate enough. While I would love to work with a team of engineers and resources to do all that, and while I do appreciate it, I would rather keep it as basic as possible.

@BilalBahadırAkbulut I did this alone. But if you are looking to make measurements (A) with more than one instrument, (B) with the same instrument or with more than one where you want similar readings for similar situations... then you need to grapple with the problem. That doesn't mean going to great expense and time. But it does mean understanding what you are getting and what you are not getting, depending on how you handle things. Do you have any idea at all how much intensity variation there is between pixels across an array in a one or two grating spectro? For example?

Sorry, haven't got a clue.

@BilalBahadırAkbulut Then get out a logbook and start the process of learning. I spent six months and traveled to live with an expert for three weeks, in his home with he and his wife, while educating myself on the topic. This isn't a voltmeter. Ocean Optics would certainly calibrate units before shipping. And you can ship them back for calibration later, too. Etc. But you need a process for this. That is, unless all you care about is seeing numbers but having no way to compare one measurement to another one. (I call that "getting pretty pictures" that look cute but do little by way of value.)

Okay, thank you for your insights. I'll keep on with my proof of concept project. I don't think the comments section is the place for this conversation. If you have any questions about my question, I'll try to answer them instead.

@BilalBahadırAkbulut For example, I can ship you plans to make a rectangular box out of card-stock, elmer's glue, and a razor blade. Cheap (pennies.) And it uses a standard re-writable CD ROM or DVD (different designs) which is also very cheap to make a box that you can use that is precise enough to easily separate mercury doublet at 576.959 nm and 579.065 nm just by eye. But it is just a toy. Wonderful to use to look at LED lights, for example. Or fluorescent tube lights. Great toy. But still a toy.

@BilalBahadırAkbulut Okay. Accepted. I'll stop writing. Want me to remove my comments above? Happy to do so if you feel it may interfere with your question.

No, I think they're fine, thank you though...
